# Eclipse plugin doesn't work in CDT

Tags: java, eclipse, pde

i have implemented an eclipse plug-in that runs very well in the test workbench, *Eclipse IDE* for `PHP` Developers and *Eclipse IDE* for `Java`Developers but doesn't work in *Eclipse CDT*. There is no error messages, so i dont't know, why.

My plug-in adds a popup menu entry and executes an action. I notices the plug-in stops after this line:

```
 IFile file = (IFile) ((IStructuredSelection) wbw.getSelectionService().getSelection()).getFirstElement();
```

All IDEs run on kubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selection returned by the selection service is often a user interface object rather than an `IFile`. You need to use the `IAdapterManager` to adapt this object to a file.

```java
Object selected = ((IStructuredSelection) wbw.getSelectionService().getSelection()).getFirstElement();

IAdapterManager manager = Platform.getAdapterManager();

IFile file = (IFile)manager.getAdapter(selected, IFile.class);
```